# SciKit Learn: Multilayer perceptron early stopping, restore best weights

Tags: neural-networks, scikit-learn, perceptron

In the SciKit documentation of the [MLP](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html?highlight=mlp#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier) classifier, there is the `early_stopping` flag which allows to stop the learning if there is not any improvement in several iterations. However, it does not seem specified if the best weights found are restored or the final weights are those obtained at the last iteration. If not, is possible to restore the best weights found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**.

Inspecting the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L691), we see that the internal function `_update_no_improvement_count` keeps track of the best coefficients in cases where the validation score doesn't improve

(line 580)

```py
    def _update_no_improvement_count(self, early_stopping, X_val, y_val):
        if early_stopping:
            # compute validation score, use that for stopping
            self.validation_scores_.append(self.score(X_val, y_val))

            if self.verbose:
                print("Validation score: %f" % self.validation_scores_[-1])
            # update best parameters
            # use validation_scores_, not loss_curve_
            # let's hope no-one overloads .score with mse
            last_valid_score = self.validation_scores_[-1]

            if last_valid_score < (self.best_validation_score_ +
                                   self.tol):
                self._no_improvement_count += 1
            else:
                self._no_improvement_count = 0

            if last_valid_score > self.best_validation_score_:
                self.best_validation_score_ = last_valid_score
                self._best_coefs = [c.copy() for c in self.coefs_]
                self._best_intercepts = [i.copy()
                                         for i in self.intercepts_]
```

and that the internal function `_fit_stochastic` 
restores these coefficients if `early_stopping==True`

(line 567)

```py
        if early_stopping:
            # restore best weights
            self.coefs_ = self._best_coefs
            self.intercepts_ = self._best_intercepts
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the function will restore best weights, see the snippet below, taken from [this link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L575).

```python
if early_stopping:
            # restore best weights
            self.coefs_ = self._best_coefs
            self.intercepts_ = self._best_intercepts
```

Please do make sure to set a reasonable `validation_fraction`, default is set to `0.1`.